# Which JavaScript framework does Visual Studio natively support?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Is it jQuery? Is there a way to integrate support for the excellent ExtJS or YUI libraries?

Any news on whether Visual Studio 2010 will support another JS framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have either documented or debug versions of the framework you want to use, [VS 2008 will give you IntelliSense](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/21/vs-2008-javascript-intellisense.aspx) of the referenced JS libraries.

If you've installed the [additional IntelliSense hotfix](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/07/hotfix-to-enable-vsdoc-js-intellisense-doc-files-is-now-available.aspx) [KB958502](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958502/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1736), you can take advantage of VS automatically finding copies of documented JS files named .vsdoc.js or .debug.js next to your referenced minified versions.

Going forward, VS 2010 will have even more support for JavaScript, working out parameter types from usage, etc.

Microsoft have started offering **support** for jQuery - which is different to VS supporting a JavaScript framework - this means that you can phone MS up and say your site isn't working with jQuery, and they will help you fix it (as a standard support incident, like they would if you found an issue in VS itself, or IIS, or even Word).

Answer (score 6):

I have only seen that Microsoft will support JQuery.  But that has less to do with Visual Studio and IIS, and more to do with Microsoft Support practices.  JQuery will be shipped with Visual Studio 2010, the Microsoft AJAX Framework, and the ASP.Net MVC Framework (happening now).

But you can use any JavaScript library you want, and if you have the correct service packs you should also get a bit of intelesence with Visual Studio 2008.

The one "extra" JQuery gives you that I have not seen (yet) from other JavaScript libraries is a version of their library with Visual Studio comments in them, giving better intelesense directives.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any javascript framework you like.  JQuery comes packaged with .Net, but it's not your only option.

Comment: jQuery only comes bundled with ASP.NET MVC, not with .NET in general yet - I believe it may be more bundled with .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can use any frame work you want, but be careful of frameworks conflict i spent hell of a time to figure out Jquery problems with other framework, until i discovered that it has problem with moo tools regarding syntax, here is the link it will save you hell of a time.

http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/3dabd31a8ab60505?pli=1

http://forum.mootools.net/viewtopic.php?pid=26204